# Improving PostGIS performance for spatial intersection

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I have a fairly large table with line geometries, representing roads (about 900k rows) and a table with polygons representing land use (about 8k rows). I want to know what type of land each road passes through. For most it is only one, but some pass through two different polygons.

I've written the following statements and tested them on a subset of the road data (around 4.5k), and they work (take around 33 seconds to create the view). I've tried running it with the full table, but my computer crashed after 2 hours.
Is there any way to optimize the query, so it runs a bit faster?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ways_lc AS 
    SELECT w.osm_id, string_agg(l.label_modified, ', ') AS landcover FROM waysdk w 
    JOIN land_cover l ON ST_Intersects(w.geometry, l.geometry) GROUP BY osm_id;

UPDATE waysdk w SET landscape = landcover
    FROM ways_lc lc WHERE w.osm_id = lc.osm_id;
```

There are indexes and spatial indexes on both tables. The reason I'm creating a materialized view is to also create indexes on the view, but it didn't make any difference from performance.

I have tried looking into PostgreSQL/PostGIS performance issues, but have mainly encountered solutions for very large and complex geometries, which isn't the case here.

Running EXPLAIN for the query returns this (which I to be honest have a hard time interpreting):

```
HashAggregate  (cost=15696875.24..16296475.21 rows=958763 width=40) (never executed)
    Group Key: w.osm_id
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.15..12379366.37 rows=21489936 width=27) (never executed)
          Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..10229372.77 rows=8954140 width=27) (never executed)
              ->  Seq Scan on waysdk w  (cost=0.00..168900.85 rows=399485 width=142) (never executed)
              ->  Index Scan using idx_land_cover_geometry on land_cover l  (cost=0.15..25.17 rows=1 width=954) (never executed)
                      Index Cond: (geometry && w.geometry)
                      Filter: st_intersects(w.geometry, geometry)
```

Comment: Even for the subset it is way too slow. Make sure to vacuum + analyze both tables. Also if the polygons are huge you may want to subdivide them first.

Comment: Off topic, but you may want to use `string_agg(DISTINCT l.label_modified, ', ')` should the line crosses several polygons of the same land-use

Comment: What is slow exactly, creating the materialized view or updating the table?

Comment: Does the update function stall even with a small subset?  Is there a circular reference in postgres if you try to update a table using a view that calls the table?   If so, you could incorporate query in the view into the update and not call the view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

I tried running both VACUUM ANALYZE and using smaller polygons, with limited improvements (26 seconds for the subsets).
The problem is with the materialized view, so I don't think a circular reference is the issue.
When attempting to run the query again this morning, even just creating the view for the subset took upwards to 2 minutes, so I'm beginning to think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Does your host have sufficient resources to run this query? How long does the query take without creating a mview?